# How to get the Caret Position from mouse clicking point in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I need to change the caret position of `RichTextBox` text to mouse clicking position. I did it in a `WPF` `RichTextBox` by using the built-in method `GetPositionFromPoint`.
But I can't find any methods like this in a `WinForms` `RichTextBox`.

Can anyone please let me know, is there any possibilites to make it work in Windows Forms?

Comment: _But I can't find any methods like this in a WinForms RichTextBox_ Try a little harder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When clicking the Text content of a `RichTextBox` control, the caret position is moved to the position of the Mouse Pointer inside the control. This position is now the current insertion point.
The caret new position can be retrieved in two ways:

Inspecting the [SelectionStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart) property:

```
int caretPosition = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
```

Using the Mouse Pointer position returned by the `MouseEventArgs`' `e.Location`.
You can use, in this case, the [GetCharIndexFromPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition) method:

```
int caretPosition = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
```

If you compare the values returned by `SelectionStart` and `GetCharIndexFromPosition`, you can verify that these values are equal.

If you want the Caret to follow the Mouse Pointer when it moves inside the Bounds of a `RichTextBox`, you can then subscribe to the `MouseMove` event and use this method to translate the Mouse Pointer position to a char index position (you need to first click inside a `RichTextBox` control):

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox rtb = sender as RichTextBox;
    rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
}
```

The Line position is returned by the [GetLineFromCharIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex) method:
(The [Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines) array refers to the text parts separated by a line feed (`\n` in a `RichTextBox`)

```
int CaretPositionLine = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(caretPosition);
```

Comment: What if the RichTextBox only contains images and not text?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn What about it? You care about a *char index* when there's no text? Anyway, each Image should occupy a *char position*